# Check parameters of a function in a Python

Tags: python, function

For example, I have a function, that generates procedural noise

```
def procedural_noise(width, height, seed):
   ...
```

All of the parameters of this function should be positive. I suppose, that me need to check it and throw exception if on of parameters is non-positive. Is it a good (pythonic way) approach?

**Let us suppose, that I am right. Which is the best way to check parameters?**

---

I can write the checkers for each of parameters:

```
def procedural_noise(width, height, seed):
    if width <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Width should be positive")
    if height <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Height should be positive")
    if seed <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Seed should be positive")
    ...
```

It should be clearly for programmer when he will get exception, what he should to correct, but it's not good-looking in my opinion.

The following code is easier, but it is too far from ideal:

```
def procedural_noise(width, height, seed):
    if width <= 0 or height <= 0 or seed <= 0:
        raise ValueError("All of the parameters should be positive")
    ...
```

---

**The last question: which is the best way to write tests with `unittest` framework, that checks types of parameters and their values?**

I can write the following function in a test class:

```
def test_positive(self):
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, main.procedural_noise, -10, -10, 187)
```

Is it a correct solution?

---

*UPD: I upvoted all answers, because each of them have a useful information for me, but I can't select the best answers of them (I suppose that it is fair to select most voted question tomorrow)*

Comment: Something is wrong here - zero is not positive, but no error would be raised :)

Comment: Sorry. There was night in my country :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also this could be a nice use case for function annotations (in Python 3).  Example:

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps    

def positive(name, value):
    if value < 0:
        raise ValueError(name + " must be positive")

def check_params(f):
    signature = inspect.signature(f)
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        bound_arguments = signature.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, value in bound_arguments.arguments.items():
            annotation = signature.parameters[name].annotation
            if annotation is inspect.Signature.empty:
                continue
            annotation(name, value)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@check_params
def procedural_noise(width: positive, height: positive, seed: positive):
    pass # ...
```

It's a little bit of inspect-fu in the `check_params` decorator (inspired by [github.com/ceronman/typeannotations](https://github.com/ceronman/typeannotations/blob/master/annotation/typed.py#L480)), but provides pretty nice and flexible way to check function arguments - without any `if`s, `for`s or other noise-code in the type-checked functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is very interesting solution. In particular, because I haven't encountered such nice application of function annotations before.

Answer (score 6):

I would do it this way:

```
def procedural_noise(width, height, seed):
    check_positive(width, "width")
    check_positive(height, "height")
    check_positive(seed, "seed")

def check_positive(value, name):
    if value < 0:
        raise ValueError(name + " must be positive")
```

---

Another idea - a little "hack":

```
def procedural_noise(width, height, seed):
    check_positive(width=width)
    check_positive(height=height)
    check_positive(seed=seed)

def check_positive(**kwargs):
    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError(name + " must be positive")
```

Which, well, could be called also this way:

```
def procedural_noise(width, height, seed):
    check_positive(width=width, height=height, seed=seed)
```

This is almost the same as in other answers, but this way the original function `procedural_noise` is kept pretty clean of any argument processing except the very basic information. It's more *semantic* :)

Comment: Maybe `check_positive(**kwargs)`  for `check_positive(width=width, height=height, seed=seed)`?

Comment: I already upvoted ;) I think it has other useful uses like `check_positive(area=width*height)`. Also, for completeness you may say something for testing.

Comment: Thanks! This solution is more familiar to me. What do you think about a nesting function `check_positive` in a function `procedural_noise` if I will use that function once?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first question, using [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module:

```
import inspect

def procedural_noise(width, height, seed):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)

    for name in args:
        if values[name] < 0:
             raise ValueError(name + " should be positive")

procedural_noise(3, -66, 2)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\hack.py", line 10, in <module>
    procedural_noise(3, -6, 2)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\hack.py", line 8, in procedural_noise
    raise ValueError(name + " should be positive")
ValueError: height should be positive
```

---

Otherwise, you could also use [dictionary packing](http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments) this way:

```
def procedural_noise(**params):
    for name in params.keys():
        if params[name] < 0:
             raise ValueError(name + " should be positive")

procedural_noise(width=3, height=6, seed=-2)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\hack.py", line 6, in <module>
    procedural_noise(width=3, height=6, seed=-2)
  File "...\hack.py", line 4, in procedural_noise
    raise ValueError(name + " should be positive")
ValueError: seed should be positive
```

---

Comment: However, this requires named parameters when the function is called - something the OP may not want.

Comment: That's certainly one way to go about it. Here, have an upvote.

Comment: Thank you very much. I enjoyed the last your solution with `dictionary_packing`, but it have one disadvantage: the programmer, that will use this function, will not see a hint with list of parameters of the function in his IDE.

Comment: Glad I could help :) You're right. That's not the best solution for your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
def procedural_noise(width, height, seed):
    for key,val in locals().items():
        if val < 0:
             raise ValueError(key + " should be positive")
```

Comment: Thanks! There is in our country verb: "brevity is the sister of talent" :)

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself doing this a lot, maybe a decorator will make your code more readable:

```
def assert_positive(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for i, v in enumerate(args):
            if v < 0:
                raise ValueError('The parameter at position %d should be >= 0' % i)
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if v < 0:
                raise ValueError('The parameter %s should be >= 0' % k)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then you could just declare your function like this:

```
@assert_positive
def procedural_noise(width, height, seed=0):
    ...
```

It would raise exceptions like this:

```
>>> procedural_noise(0,-1,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "argument_checking.py", line 5, in wrapper
    raise ValueError('The parameter at position %d should be >= 0' % i)
ValueError: The parameter at position 1 should be >= 0
>>> procedural_noise(0,0,seed=-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "argument_checking.py", line 8, in wrapper
    raise ValueError('The parameter %s should be >= 0' % k)
ValueError: The parameter seed should be >= 0
```

The pythonic way is usually to not check your arguments too much, but there are counterexamples. Examples of builtins that do completely different things:

- `range(-1)` - Looks funny, but is fine, returns `[]`
- `time.sleep(-1)` - Crashes with an `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` which I think is just Python's way of saying that a system call returned an error. Maybe I'm lucky that system calls do argument checking...
- `chr(-1)` - `ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)`

Comment: Thanks. Could you advice some a stuff to read about checking arguments in Python? It is very interesting theme, because I know, that type checking is not approval approach, but there are plenty of situations where is a using variable with incorrect type will crash the work of function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) builtin -- `all` takes an iterable and returns `True` if all of the items in the iterable are truthy. So for your example, since all positive numbers are truthy, you could write:

```
def procedural_noise(width, height, seed):
  if all((width, height, seed)):
    # Do stuff
  else:
    raise ValueError("You biffed it.")
```

Note the double parens -- that's because I'm passing the tuple `(width, height, seed)` to `all` -- I can't just write `all(width, height, seed)`, because `all` expects one iterable argument, like a tuple.

---

With respect to the testing question, supposing that the name of the module in which `procedural_noise` is defined is named `foo`, then in your test file you can use `assertRaises` with the `with` keyword, as follows:

```
import foo
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_positive(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
      foo.procedural_noise(-10, -10, 187)
```

Read more about it at the [unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

Comment: This is simply incorrect. Your code will raise an Error only if all three inputs are 0. Even otherwise, this is clearly not what the OP is looking for, he explicitly states he wants to provide specific exception messages.

Comment: You're right, I had originally written the example as `if all((args)): do stuff`. I've believe I've fixed it -- if you place the code in a conditional it should have the expected behavior.

Comment: It is not quite suit for me, but anyway thanks for answer. As for testing question, I wrote, that my function is in a test class, so I have a code, that look a like your code. I asked, is it correct to use `assertRaises` and `ValueError` in my situation?

Comment: Yes, it is correct to use `assertRaises` to check that an error was raised. You might want to try checking each argument individually in the test just to be sure that your code catches all cases, that would involve several `assertRaises` statements.